# Convert two models attribute in a json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I am on ruby on rails and i have two models, the goal is to do a search of the website on two models, i am using twitter typeahead but the issue i have is the json has to be one object.

I am not sure what is the best way to convert my two objects into one. Here the code

```
@users= Search.user(params[:query])
@articles= Search.article(params[:query])
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json {
    render :json => {
     :art=> @articles.map(&:title),
     :user=> @users.map(&:first_name)
  }}
  end
end
```

I am not sure what the best way or i can't seem to find the best documentation to merge these two models into one. I dont know if to_json, as_json, or concat would be the best.

The idea is to have a result of the following json from

```
{"art":["John","Serge","Dean","feng","Heather"],"user":["Ontario high school teachers drop next week's walkout plan","Air Canada to appeal Quebec court ruling on Aveos"]}
```

To the following

```
{"result":["John","Serge","Dean","feng","Heather", "Ontario high school teachers drop next week's walkout plan","Air Canada to appeal Quebec court ruling on Aveos"]}
```

Comment: What are you trying to get back to the json request? There you are getting a couple of users and articles, and then you answer with a hash, where the key :art points to an array of titles for articles, and the key :user points to an array of first_name for the users.

Comment: The idea is just an array of articles and users, so i can output back the result on my autocomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you want to get an array of both users and articles:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json  { render :json => {:art => @articles, 
                                  :user => @users }}

  end
end
```

---

Based on your edit:

```
format.json {
  render :json => {
    result => @articles.map(&:title) | @users.map(&:first_name)
}}
```

---

Based on last comment, just trap the nil issue:

```
format.json {
  render :json => {
    result => (@articles.map(&:title) || []) | (@users.map(&:first_name) || [])
}}
```

Comment: but i dont want it to be two different arrays, i want it to be has follow {"res":["John","Serge","Dean","feng","Heather","Carmen","test", "First Nations meeting with PM in jeopardy",...}

Comment: I am having issue if its a nilclass

Comment: @Jseb See my answer with regards to json templates. You can set up your json however you want really easily

Comment: @jamesw that's nice for complex json results, however what he wants to give back is a simple json result, building a new view and using a builder its not a pragmatic solution

Comment: @rorra There is nothing not pragmatic about json templates. Dead easy to set up, take minuites to produce and totally configurable to meet your needs. Jseb is obviously struggling to produce the needed output, templates solve the problem in a way that I believe Jseb will find intuitive.

Comment: and then he will have to learn a builder syntax for something he can accomplish on a single ruby line of code, he will have to setup json views, and just to give back a single array of strings, I still think that's not pragmatic unless he has to build a complex json structure that will end in too much responsibility for an action controller

Comment: Thank you both, I was able to implement rorra right away, however, this is just the start of my project, I will look in Rabl has it sound easy to set up, although i must say i dont like gem, in term of development, but rails has limits and in complex solution it will come handy

Answer (score 2):

Can I suggest that you use a JSON view template. There are many options for you but the two most popular are RABL and JBuilder. I can highly recommend the RABL gem.

There is a reason for their popularity, they make rendering json a breeze

You can find the RABL gem here https://github.com/nesquena/rabl

You can find the JBuilder gem here https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

There are excellent railsasts on both of them showing how to use them.

RABL
http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl

JBuilder
http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder

I favour RABL purely out of personal preference you should look at both options to see which best suits you.

Adding a gem is not normally something I would recommend but I think you will find that either of these solutions will match your needs

Comment: I am reading rabl, the only thing i am confused is that i dont see them as associated, do i need to have child, or is there an other way to simply render two objects

Comment: That depends on how you want your json to be output. You could just use nodes or you can use child if that suits your requirements. The best thing to do is to show how the json should be rendered then manipulate the template to produce the json you need